# Jenkins job execution in script consol

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am unable to execute following script in jenkins script consol.

```
job('testjob') {
  using('template_job')
  configure { node ->
    node / scm / branches / 'hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec' / name('main')
  }
}
```

i am getting below error

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.job() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, Script1$_run_closure1) values: [testjob, Script1$_run_closure1@4eaafbe6]
Possible solutions: run(), run(), any(), wait(), dump(), grep()
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you are trying to run is a [Job DSL](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/) script.
It is not intended to run in the  Jenkins *script console* menu and therefore you get that exception, the DSL script should be executed in a dedicated **Process Job DSLs** build step (usually in a freestyle job). Use the following [Official Documentation Guide](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/#:%7E:text=First%2C%20start%20a%20Jenkins%20instance,(%27echo%20Hello%20World!%27)) to get started with the Jon DSL plugin and instructions on how to use it.
In addition here is an excellent [Tutorial](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Tutorial---Using-the-Jenkins-Job-DSL) for using the Job DSL Plugin.

BTW, you can use the [Job DSL Playground](http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/) to create and test your configure blocks, but the playground only supports the DSL API that is available in the online API Reference - as oppose to the complete DSL API reference that is available in your Jenkins installation at https://your.jenkins.installation/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html.